# Does React Native have a font-relative size units?

Tags: react-native, responsive-design

I have to set a width of a `View` in term of the current font size. So I am wondering if React Native have an analogue of the Web's `1em`?

I have found a solution with `PixelRatio`:

```
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

// ...

<View style={{ width: 100 * PixelRatio.getFontScale() }} />
```

But it is too complicated and obscure, in my opinion.
Is there a more simple and clean way to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I eventually found an answer in the React Native [API Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/layout-props#width):

> `width` sets the width of this component.
>
> It works similarly to width in CSS, but in React Native you must use points or percentages. Ems and other units are not supported.

So the `getFontScale()` is the only possible solution.